# Deployment of Celeryd to the AWS Beanstalks

Tags: celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celeryd

I'm working on python web site which uses Celery for running long running background procesess. I plan to deploy my web site with celery worker to Beanstalk container.

Please share you expirence or ideas how to deploy and run celeary workers as demons at Beanstalk container.

Comment: I suggested a solution that uses supervisord to run the celery daemon in a similar question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761468/how-do-you-run-a-worker-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk/22533800#22533800

Answer (score 0):

I built a custom AMI using [AWS linux ami](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/) as a base, with celery set to run at start up in daemon mode. I customised the AMI so eveything was running under Python 2.7 rather than the default 2.6. This meant rebuilding mod_wsgi and using virtual environments.

Comment: You can do that much simpler without the need of a custom AMI, see my answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761468/how-do-you-run-a-worker-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk/22533800#22533800