# Can Celery run on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I'm looking for a straight-forward way to run Celery on an Elastic Beanstalk environment. Does this exist, or do I need to use SQS instead?

I have tried putting a line in the the .config file without good results. This is my .config file:

```
container_commands:   
  01_syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true   
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "./manage.py collectstatic --noinput"   
  03_migrate:
    command: "./manage.py migrate --noinput"   
  04_start_celery:
    command: "./manage.py celery worker &"
```

When I ssh to the EC2 server and run `ps -ef | grep celery` it shows that Celery isn't running.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you expand on "without good results"? What are the results? Are there any error messages you can show us?

Comment: Good point. I updated the question details. Celery simply isn't running on the box (no error that I can see).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Celery doesn't show up because the container commands are run prior to reboot of the webserver during deployment. Basically, your celery workers get wiped out after the machine restarts.

I would suggest starting celery by using post deployment hooks.

See http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/ and [How do you run a worker with AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761468/how-do-you-run-a-worker-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk?rq=1)

Comment: Actually, I was able to get this working on Elastic Beanstalk in a much cleaner way using https://github.com/rfk/django-supervisor to run celery workers as daemons that persist through a deploy. I did have to add some post deployment hooks to ensure a fresh starting of this service though.