# Configuring Celery with Django using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, celery, mod-wsgi

I'm using Django 1.6 and Celery 3.1 (so not using django-celery). 
My WSGI file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/code_base/backend/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_django_project.settings.production'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Starting the Apache server everything works as expected as if I was running `manage.py runserver`. This is fine for my webserver, but what configuration do I need when I want the server to be a worker instead (similar to `celery -A my_django_project worker -l info`)?

Comment: [yellowcaps answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761468/how-do-you-run-a-worker-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk) actually turned out to be the best solution for me

Answer (score 2):

Usually in production you would want to run the worker as a daemon. There are a few ways to achieve that, documented in the [Celery Guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html), but personally I prefer to run the workers under [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).