# EC2 .bashrc and .bash_profile re-setting

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, pycurl, amazon-linux-2

Reason I'm asking: pycurl requires both `libcurl-devel` and `openssl-devel`. To install these, I have these two lines the my .bash_profile:

```
sudo yum install libcurl-devel
sudo yum install -y openssl-devel
```

Previously, I just ran those commands in the terminal while ssh'd into the EC2 instance.

However, it seems that at random times those lines are cleared from the `.bashrc` and `.bashprofile`, and the packages no longer exist in the instance. Why is this happening? Is the EC2 instance refreshing to a clean version at some point? If so, why? And how can I ensure those two packages are default installed on every instance?

When I `eb deploy` I still see the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` contain the `yum install` commands. The timing the files are refreshed seems random, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You should not be installing software (which only  needs to be done once) from `.bash_profile` (which gets sourced each time you login). `sudo yum install pycurl`, wherever you run that, should install both `pycurl` and all its dependencies.

Comment: @chepner the issue is that `libcurl-devel` and `openssl-devel` aren't python packages, so they aren't installed

Comment: I'm assuming you are using `pip`, not `yum`, to install `pycurl`? This is one reason why it's still useful to use language-agnostic package managers. You can create an RPM for `pycurl` that does little more than run `pip install pycurl` and includes `libcurl-devel` and `openssl-devel` as dependencies.

Comment: @chepner yep, you're correct. Do you have any resources I could reference? That sounds to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a `linix.config` file within my `/.ebextensions` folder.

Contents of `linix.config`:

```
commands:
  libcurl-devel:
    command: sudo yum install -y libcurl-devel
    ignoreErrors: true
  openssl-devel:
    command: sudo yum install -y openssl-devel
    ignoreErrors: true
```